# Solve "You must choose a build." when upload app in iTunes

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-app

When upload **ipa** file by Xcode and the results successfuly uploade the **ipa** is not show in Activity tab ,but show in version history and when click on button **submit for review** shown alert missing **"You must choose a build"**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please give me advise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select your uploaded ipa from the `Build` section in order to submit your app for review.

An uploaded build might take some time to show up in app store connect, due to the fact that it needs to pass Apple's automatic processing.

**Update**: Actually a plus button will be shown next to `Build` that can be used to select your build
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is not click on submit for review?

Comment: @tele if there is a mistake in your build you will be notified through an email. If not,  your build will pop up in the `Build` section.

Comment: my .ipa file not showing in build section after uploading it.

Comment: @tele if you haven't got an email regarding any error, your build will be shown sooner or later.

Comment: i haven't received any emails yet and the select a build button in the image isn't showing.